# Combine multiple maven projects into single in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have one maven project with pom.xml.
This project refers another 2 projects.
These 2 projects have their own pom.xml in their respective folders.
So when I build base pom.xml other 2 projects also get built.

Now here is what I did

a) Build base project (This built 2 subprojects as well).
b) Used `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to export base project.
c) Imported base project into eclipse using Eclipse menu File-> Import existing Maven project.

After importing it created 3 different projects in Eclipse.
As methods for 3 projects get called from each other it gives many errors.
What I want is after importing it should create single project and all the code will be in a single project.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a multi-module project. This will allow you to define a top-level project and the structure of it's dependencies. It will likely still require some refactoring, but it should be relatively modest.

Maven website: [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

[A third party guide](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is **NO.**

Unless you **manually** merge/refactor these 3 projects into one.

pom.xml is per project, here there are 3 poms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I manually merge all 3 projects into one?